# Raster - Error NOTE: rgdal::checkCRSArgs: no proj_defs.dat in PROJ.4 shared files

Tags: raster, r, rgdal

I am brand new to using geographic data in R and I keep running into an error:

> NOTE: rgdal::checkCRSArgs: no proj_defs.dat in PROJ.4 shared files

I believe that this is due to an old version of PROJ (4.9.0), and I have found a good deal of discussion surrounding this topic but I have been unsuccessful in fixing this issue - mostly due to that I don't fully understand the answers posted on this topic i.e. "add missing file to proj folder" What file? Is my project folder the same as my working directory?.  I tried reinstalling `rgdal`, with the following commands:

```
install.packages("rgdal",
                 configure.args = c("--with-project-include=/p/bin/proj4/include",
                                    "--with-proj-lib=/p/bin/proj4/lib",
                                    "--with-proj-share=/p/bin/proj4/share/proj"))
```

But I get the same error. 
I am a Mac user. Can someone walk me through how to deal with this error?

Comment: The newest `PROJ4` version is 4.9.3. I am not completely sure but I assume it could be fixed by just installing the newest version of `gdal` (currently 2.1.2) system-wide. If you use homebrew, just do `brew install gdal2` and follow the instructions. Then restart R and check if everything is working now.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I don't use homebrew. I tried downloading the latest version of Proj-4, but when I installed it, I got some strange messages: `Last login: Sat Jan 14 19:21:52 on ttys000
LM-SF-NHIRE3:~ XXXXXXX$ /Users/XXXXXXX/Downloads/proj.4-master/INSTALL ; exit;
/Users/XXXXXXX/Downloads/proj.4-master/INSTALL: line 1: Basic: command not found/Users/XXXXXXX/Downloads/proj.4-master/INSTALL: line 2: ==================: command not found
/Users/XXXXXXX/Downloads/proj.4-master/INSTALL: line 4: These: command not found` There were many other lines returning the same message. Any ideas?

Comment: Hard to tell what you did wrong / what's missing based on these error messages. If you want a (professional) working setup with up-to-date libraries, I strongly recommend using homebrew (or any other package manager).

Answer (score 2):

There are different approaches compiling the `PROJ4` library on macOS:

1. Use the package manager [`homebrew`](http://brew.sh/index_de.html). Fist add the `osgeo4mac` tap: `brew tap osgeo/osgeo4mac`). Then install `proj` and `gdal2` using `brew install <formula>`. (**Recommended**)
2. Compile from source: Before doing so, remove all existing `PROJ4` installations. Multiple installations often cause problems. Then either compile from the [Github source](https://github.com/OSGeo/proj.4) or use [this guide](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/gis/install/geolibs/). When compiling the Github source, be aware that you need to call `./autogen.sh` before you can do `./configure` (see [this issue](https://github.com/OSGeo/proj.4/issues/352)).

If you also want to upgrade `GDAL`, make sure before that `PROJ4` is installed and configured correctly.

Comment: For the `brew install gdal2` I get the following error 

`brew install gdal2
Error: No available formula with the name "gdal2" 
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
Error: No formulae found in taps.`

Comment: @Andy you need to call `brew tap osgeo/osgeo4mac` before because the formula is available in the `osgeo4mac` tap